# Liferay : Page template inside a portlet war

Tags: liferay

Can we include a new layout template inside a portlet war? And I want that template to be used for a particular page.

Regards
Vishal G

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here: http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout+Template

Answer (score 0):

This would exists in lar import and export only and not pre packaged win war.